# Extracting columns from an excel file with python ignoring customised cell settings

Tags: python, excel

i a trying to bring the Data from many Excel files together.
There are columns for Company name, city, and costs.

The problem is:
on a lot of the hundreds of excel sheets, the costs cells are customized. if i read them with python they are shown as datetime.datetime. i have no idea why python change a customized cell to a timestamp and i have a lot less ideas how to solve this. i already tryed a lot but it mostly says cant convert daytime.daytime to int oder float.... any ideas?

```
pfad3 = r"C://Users//Schwamm//Desktop//Submission//test1//"
datenlage = glob.glob(pfad3 + "*.xlsx")
i = 0
concat_all_files = pd.DataFrame()
for file in datenlage:
    i = i + 1
    filename = datenlage
    #DF = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, index_col=0, header=0,usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])
    DF = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, skiprows=None, nrows=None, usecols=None, header=1, index_col=None)
    concat_all_files_single = pd.concat(DF,sort=False)
    concat_all_files_single['Dateiname']=(file.split("\\")[-1])
    concat_all_files_single['Laufendenummer'] = (i)
    concat_all_files = concat_all_files.append(concat_all_files_single)
    #concat_all_files = concat_all_files.append(datenlage)
print(concat_all_files)
```

Image: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/8097/rzK9ms.jpg

Comment: Excel is storing all these values as doubles. Your image suggests that some cells have been formatted as dates, which may be why `pandas` is trying to convert them to dates, even when they aren't. You can try adding a parameter to `read_excel` of `dtype=object`, or you can choose to specify a particular type for a given column. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: It is worth remembering that how Excel stores a value and how it displays it are different things. In order to see the underlying datatype in Excel, select the cell and hit Ctrl-Shift-#. This removes all formatting and just displays the raw underlying value. It looks like all your values could be doubles, but they might also be strings (especially as they seem to be left-justified). I do suspect your data is in string format, so pandas will interpret strings that look like dates as dates.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** *Question needs improvment and some more debugging details*

Per default `pandas` tries to sniff the types of column values while reading in, but you can force it to handle the `costs` column as `str`:

```
pd.read_excel(file, dtype={'costs':'object'})
```

You also can force `pandas` to read the whole data as `str`:

```
pd.read_excel(file, dtype=object)
```

### EDIT

As DS_London mentioned correctly - To ensure the doubles are imported:

```
pd.read_excel(file, dtype = {'costs':np.float64})
```

Comment: Or indeed `dtype = {'costs':np.float64}` if you want to ensure that doubles are imported.

Comment: Thanks - Indeed, to work on the data definitely the final approach.

Comment: if i try this, i got this error:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime' ---------------------  and this is how the excel cell is formated: _-* #.##0,00 _D_M_-;-* #.##0,00 _D_M_-;_-* "-"?? _D_M_-;_-@_-